# Running one python script from another script with command line argument having executable in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, executable

I am trying to run a python script within another python script. Which will run 10 times and produce 10 outputs.

I want to run `program1.py` inside `program2.py`. Now my `program1.py` was initially taking a C executable inside it and it takes 1 command line argument.

The `program1.py` looks like below:

```
import os
import sys
dataset = sys.argv[1]

os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5 -u -f {dataset}")
os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset}")
os.system(f"/home/Dev/c4.5rules -u -f {dataset} > Temp")

f = open('Temp')
# Some code
```

Where c4.5 and c4.5rules are the name of the executable files. To run this I was using `python3 program1.py dataset_name`

Now I am trying to put this `program1.py` inside `program2.py` and I am trying this below approach:

```
import os
import subprocess

# Some code
for track in range(0, 10):
    with open(f'Train_{track}', 'r') as firstfile, open(f'DF_{track}.data', 'w') as secondfile:
        for line in firstfile:
            secondfile.write(line)
    os.system("/home/Dev/program1.py DF_track")
    #subprocess.Popen("/home/Dev/program1.py DF_track", shell=True)
```

Where I simply want to get the output of `program1.py` 10 times and want to use `DF_track` as the command line input for each output generation.

Using above approach I am getting lots of error. Please help.

Edit_1 :

Actually whenever I am trying to run, my cursor is not working, it is freezing, so unable to copy the errors.

Here are some of them :

```
1. attempt to perform an operation not allowed by security policy.
2. syntax error : word expected (expecting ")")
```

Comment: "I am getting lots of error": such as?

Comment: Show the full (or at least a substantial part) of the error(s) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You need a shebang line at the start of program1.py (`#! /usr/bin/python3`), and you need to make it executable (`chmod +x program1.py`).  But the much smarter method would be to put the `program1.py` code into a function, and just `import` it into program2.  It's silly to start a new process for this.

Comment: I have edited the question and added some of the errors. I have just started to learn python so unable to figure out properly how to approach this.

Comment: `os.system("/home/Dev/program1.py DF_track")` why to run python script via system command - why dont you import it and use it?

Comment: @balderman can you please help me saying how should I do that? That will be a great help.

Comment: @Dev see my answer. This is the "normal" way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine I have 2 files, the first file is `a.py` and the other is `b.py` and I want to call the `a.py` from `b.py`.

The content of a.py is:

```
print('this is the a.py file')
```

and the content of b.py is:

```py
import os

stream = os.popen('python3 a.py')
output = stream.read()

print(output)
```

Now when I call `b.py` from terminal I get the output I expect which is a.py print statment

```sh
user@mos ~ % python3 b.py
this is the a.py file
```

You can do this with `subprocess` too instead of `os` module.

Here is a nice blog I found online where I got the code from: https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/

Comment: Thank you so much .According to my code how am I supposed to use that DF_track as my command line input here?

Answer (score 0):

See the example below.

**a.py**

```
def do_something():
  pass
```

**b.py**

```
from a import do_something

do_something()
```

Comment: this example lacks detail (needs elaboration). you are simply showing how to create an import in another file and calling that method, what are you achieving here.

Comment: Thank you for this. But according to my code can you please guide me saying how can I use that DF_track as my command line input then?